# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file:

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I just updated my HAXM to version 6.2.1 . When I run the emulator I get an error message in the event log of the android studio:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file:
>   /Users/blabla/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_25.avd/userdata.img

Nevertheless, the app runs without any problems in the emulator. Does anybody know the solution not to get this message again? Thank You

Edit: Now it works right. I closed and opened android studio

Comment: Do you get it everytime? I got it only the first time I ran the emulator. I guess it creates it if it's missing

Comment: @Chiptus yes I didn't saw the message again. I should have edited my post. Sorry

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As per the comment of @user4938227 (and my experience) it seems like it's a one time warning the should happen at the first run of the emulator. Avd creates the file and on the following runs it shouldn't appear.

Comment: they still didn't fix it, they could just show message like "some file does not exist we will create it for you", but no they still show those scary messages

Answer (score 3):

## Update

You need to update Android Emulator and HAXM,

- Go to `Tools > SDK Manager`
- Update Android Emulator and HAXM installer

[image: sc]