# Unable to 'Run App' in Android Studio - have tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times

Tags: android, virtual-machine, emulation

I'm new to coding and I'm learning to create android apps with Android Studio. Everything was working great, I was really enjoying the learning process, then one day out of nowhere the "Run App" feature stopped working.

It's been a few days of me trying to figure out what's gone wrong and it's safe to say that my level of patience has been tested. I do not know what to do because it seems like nothing is working.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times and checked all the settings. I haven't had much luck finding anything online relating to this problem. The only thing I've been able to do is start using Genymotion. However, I would still like to resolve this issue and make sure Android Studio is working how it should.

The below text is from my Event Log on Android Studio:

```
8:06 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\Alpha1\.android\avd\Nexus_5X.avd/userdata.img

8:06 PM Emulator: Failed to create vcpu 0

8:06 PM Emulator: Failed to create vcpu 0

8:06 PM Emulator: Failed to create HAX vcpu

8:06 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1
```

I would have so much appreciation for anyone that can help fix this.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895124/emulator-emulator-error-missing-initial-data-partition-file

Comment: Thank you, my issue seems to be different though, I've got the latest updates of Android Studio, I've closed and reopened the program,  created new projects with basic code, and no apps run at all.

Comment: Try creating another emulator (don't clone) with AVD manager and see if same results.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled my AMD Radeon R7 200 Series GPU software on my computer and that has allowed the emulator to start up and show my apps once again, I don't think I've completely fixed the issue though because my Logcat is constantly updating. Here's some text I extracted from the logcat:

```
04-11 11:37:40.031 1623-4820/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
04-11 11:37:40.282 1623-4820/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-11 11:37:40.282 1623-4820/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
04-11 11:37:40.532 1623-4820/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-11 11:37:40.532 1623-4820/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
04-11 11:37:40.782 1623-4953/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-11 11:37:40.782 1623-4953/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
04-11 11:37:40.793 2160-28845/? I/NetRec: [2446] yle.a: Refreshing scores for 1 networks.
04-11 11:37:40.796 2160-28845/? W/NetRec: [2446] yle.a: Could not send request to get scores.
04-11 11:37:40.796 2160-28845/? I/NetRec: [2446] NetRecChimeraGcmTaskService.a: Still entries pending update, scheduling new rapid_refresh_scores_task refresh.
```

If I am able to provide any further information I will.