# Android Emulator Error and doesnt work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I get this error when running:

`15:07 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\saadm\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_27.avd/userdata.img`

`15:07  Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'. No response for 15001 ms`

`15:07  Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Comment: look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895124/emulator-emulator-error-missing-initial-data-partition-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see if your system has enough memory left..